# input a string through JOptionPane with character limit

Tags: java, swing

I want to input a string through `JOptionPane` but with a character limit.
How do I do that?

```
public class LineType { 
    String line[] = new String[80];  

    void get() {
       line = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter Line (80 characters max):");
    }
}
```

Comment: `line` is an array of 80 Strings, not a String of 80 characters.

Comment: `JOptionPane` does not have a way to limit the length of the text the user enters. You have two options. Either subclass `JOptionPane` or write your own subclass of [JDialog](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JDialog.html)

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is perform some checks on the input from the user to see if they entered within your limits.

```
public class LineType { 
    String line = "";  

    void get() {
       line = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter Line (80 characters max):");
       if (line != null) { // user clicked OK and entered something?
           if (line.length() > 80) {
               // ask the user to re-enter text or something else you'd like to do here
           }
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can display any Swing component in a JOptionPane so you can customize the input with your own label and text field:

```
JTextField line = new JTextField(10);
Object[] msg = {"Enter Line (80 characters max):", line};

int result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(
    null,
    msg,
    "Enter ...",
    JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION,
    JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);

System.out.println("You entered: " + line.getText());
```

However you will still have two problems:

1. You need to be able to restrict the number of characters. To solve this you can add a `DocumentFilter` to the text field. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Implementing a DocumentFilter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html#filter) for a working example that does exactly what you want.
2. When the option pane is displayed, focus will be on the button, not the text field. To fix this check out [Dialog Focus](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2010/03/14/dialog-focus/) which will allow you to place focus on the text field when the option pane is displayed. This class adds an `AncestorListener` to the text field which will allow the text field to request focus when the option pane is displayed.

Comment: @hiba note that you need to call method `showConfirmDialog()` and not `showInputDialog()` in order to use your customized `JTextField`.